# Which step is logically incorrect in this obviously wrong manipulation?

Tags: summation, average

Consider $2\times3$.

The above multiplication is just $2\times3=2+2+2$

or more generally $a\times n= \underbrace{a+a+.....}_{n -times}$

Now consider $$\bigg \langle\frac{1}{r^2}\bigg\rangle=\bigg \langle\frac{1}{r}\times\frac{1}{r}\bigg\rangle=\bigg \langle\underbrace{\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r}+....}_{\frac{1}{r}  \ \ times}\bigg\rangle=\underbrace{\bigg \langle\frac{1}{r}\bigg\rangle+\bigg \langle\frac{1}{r}\bigg\rangle+\bigg \langle\frac{1}{r}\bigg\rangle+...}_{\frac{1}{r}\ \ times}=\frac{1}{r}\bigg \langle\frac{1}{r}\bigg\rangle$$

and therefore,

$$\bigg \langle\frac{1}{r^2}\bigg\rangle=\frac{1}{r}\bigg \langle\frac{1}{r}\bigg\rangle$$

What's up with this?

Edit: The $\langle\rangle$ denotes average.

Comment: What does the $\langle \cdot \rangle$ notation denote?

Comment: @angryavian updated.

Comment: How can you multiply  or add something by itself a non integer number of times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I will use $E[\cdot]$ instead of $\langle \cdot \rangle$ to denote [expectation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExpectationValue.html).)

By the same logic, if $N$ is an integer-valued random variable, you could argue
$$E[N] = E[\underbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}_{\text{$N$ times}}] \overset{*}{=} \underbrace{E[1] + \cdots + E[1]}_{\text{$N$ times}} = N.$$

The starred equality is the problem: this does not actually follow from the linearity of expectation property, since the number of addends is random.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate $E[\frac{1}{r^2}]$ from $E[\frac{1}{r}]$?

Comment: @Lost In general, knowing $E[X]$ does not provide enough information to compute $E[X^2]$.